# Scaling an image with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, scaling

I've used Bootstraps row feature and using the code:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
<img src="1.jpg" />
</div>
```

I have found that the image will not scale with the columns when zooming in and out.

I have tried using  to wrap my image in and this hasn't worked. I tried scaling it manually but it then changes when zooming in and out.

Finally I tried using "Xem" for height and width but this didn't work either.

How could I do this to be able to make it a scalable size to scale with bootstrap columns.

Comment: Add the class `img-responsive` to the img tag.

Comment: I answered properly so it can be accepted and so the question disappears off of unanswered lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the class `img-responsive` to the image tag.

It's documented under Images on the Bootstrap website

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

For **Bootstrap 4** and later, latest major version of Bootstrap as of this posting, they renamed `.img-responsive` to `.img-fluid` so be sure to know which version and use the correct tag.